# Why are the android unit tests not getting executed with mvn test command?

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven

Why are the android unit tests not getting executed with mvn test command
   mvn test 
its says no test cases although there are android unit tests.
Can you tell a method how to run these tests using mvn test

How to run mvn android:instrument when we enter android mvn test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.sample.projectfoundation</groupId>
 <artifactId>androidsdktest</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>apk</packaging>
 <name>AndroidSDKTest</name>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample.projectfoundation</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidsdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
   <artifactId>android</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
     <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>

     <version>3.5.3</version>
     <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <sdk>
      <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
      <platform>19</platform>
     </sdk>
     <emulator>
            <avd>mydevice</avd>
            <!-- Wait for emulator starting (3 minutes) -->
            <wait>180000</wait>
            <options>-no-skin</options>
        </emulator>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Where do you have located your tests? `src/test/java`? Furthermore have you named them accordingly to the convention `*Test.java`, `Test*.java` or `TestCase*.java` ?

Comment: if I place them in the that folder then I am getting an exception - not able to connect to host. tests are running with mvn clean install and mvn android:instrument but not running with mvn test

Comment: Can you show the pom file? And how did you named your test classes?